# How to get webpage info from app xcode

Tags: objective-c

My webpage www.example.com/hello.php, php code is:

```
 echo "Hello";
```

How can i get the information shown in my webpage from my iphone app (using Objective C).

Comment: Use `NSURLSession` to download it. SO is about helping with code, not providing code. Provide your best effort along with any sample data, expected results and problems.

Comment: I´m trying                                                                                                     NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/hello.php?var1=%@", txtUser.text];
 
 NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
 
 NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 
 if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {
    NSLog("Finally Works");
 } But it does not work :(

Comment: Add your code to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: The code in the comment has several errors that keeps it from even compiling. Also whenever possible use a form of a method that has an error parameter and at least log in when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OP's code and correcting the syntax, adding scheme to the URL and changing the `dataWithContentsOfURL:` to add an error parameter and substituting `xx` for :`txtUser.text`:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/hello.php?var1=%@", @"xx"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
NSError *error;
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
if (dataURL == nil) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"dataURL: %@", dataURL);
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"Hello"]) {
        NSLog(@"Finally Works");
    }
}
```

Output:

> url: http://example.com/hello.php?var1=xx
>   error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “hello.php” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo=0x1005036d0 {NSURL=http://example.com/hello.php?var1=xx}

Note the error.

If a method that return the response such as `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` there would be a "HTTP Error 404 - File or Directory not found" error message.

Always use the method call that returns the most information.

Answer (score -1):

Please post code in your comment as an edit to your question with the code formatted!! And then maybe we can help

And try this instead

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

    }];
```

I know this will work for a working URL, but when I go to the url you posted in the question it seems, to be broken which could be your problem

Comment: @downvoter, I cannot comment as I dont have enough rep I am just trying to help, I know this is not an answer

Comment: One problem is the code ignores the `response` which contains the 404 status code. (not the down voter)

Comment: @zaph that true, but what Im supposed to do everything for im I thought this was a pretty good start

Comment: In this particular case the result code is the key to the answer. For http cast  `NSResponse`  to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and check the `statusCode` on error. In this case it is 404. So, there is no connection error but the 404 tells us that the file was not found.

Comment: Sorry, It is just a hot-button for me when the returned information is not used, error parameters and http status codes.